# how to activate JDBC logs in wildfly

Tags: java, jdbc, eclipselink, wildfly-8

I use wildfly with EclipseLink and I want to trace SQL statements.
I configured EclipseLink according to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink), all work fine except the SQL logs. I added these properties in my persistence.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.debug" value="OFF" />
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger" />
    </properties>
```

but no SQL logs.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Please can you post your solution if you have been able to resolve this

Comment: Sorry but i have no solution, but i know that the problem appear only when i launch unit tests with Arquillian

Answer (score 7):

Here is the what works for me. I'm using Wildfly 8.2.0, eclipselink 2.5.1.

Just add

```
        <logger category="org.eclipse.persistence.sql">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>

        <logger category="org.jboss.as.jpa">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
```

to logging subsystem, in standalone.xml (in the configuration folder).

Just between

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
```

......

```
</subsystem>
```

The logging level for console handler should be at least set to DEBUG, like this:

```
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
```

The same for file-handler.

Good luck.